# What is this type of graph called

Tags: graphing-functions

I have two columns, User and Test Score.

Basically, I want to graph a sort of bell curve like chart.

The left side of the graph is the minimum score value, the right side is the maximum score value. X[] represents the number of slices between (linear).

Y(X[0]) would be the number of test scores that fall between X[0] and X[1]. It is sort of like a bell curve but it wouldn't be smooth unless there were a lot of points in between.

So two questions: 1) Is there a name of this graph? 2) Is it possible to do this with excel :-)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking of a histogram.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram

This functionality can be attained in Excel using the Column Chart type.